# how to insert a express middleware after app init?

Tags: express, middleware

app = express();
I established a socket connection after app.use(), and I want to insert another middleware after socket is connected:

```
const app = express();
app.use('/', () => {});
const wss = new ws.Server({ port: 8086 });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
   app.use((req, res, next) => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ req, res }));
      next();
   });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

but it doesn't work,can Express insert a middleware after app init?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense because `app.use(...)` will be in force for ALL users so now any user that comes along to your site will cause that ONE webSocket connection to get sent a message.  In addition, you can't JSON stringify `req` or `res `as they contain circular references and contain references to stuff like sockets that can never be stringified.  And, further, this type of code would add a new `app.use()` for every new incoming webSocket connection and they would never ever be removed even after the webSocket was gone.

Comment: Please describe what problem you're really trying to solve because this will need an entirely different approach, but we can't help without knowing what the actual design problem is.

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to make a middleware that checks if a new middleware is added. check the following example.

```js
//this is an array of functions which will work as a middlware.
let listOfMiddlewareFunctions = [];

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    //this middleware will loop through all elements in listofMiddlewareFunctions
    //and pass the parameters req, res, next to each middlewares.
    listOfMiddlewareFunction.foreach(middleware => middleware(req, res, next));
});

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    //on socket connection, the following will add the middleware to the array made before.
    const newMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ req, res }));
      next();
    };

    listOfMiddlewareFunction .add(newMiddleware);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, I fixed this problem:

```
wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
    app._mockUsedWsSend = ws.send.bind(ws);
});

// in router
const wsSend = req.app._mockUsedWsSend;
if (wsSend) {
   wsSend(JSON.stringify({
       path: req.path
   }));
}
```